# Activity sliding in android

Tags: android, android-sliding

I have listview on MainFragment. When i clicked on listview cell open second intent (DetailActivity) and this show me detailed information of clicked cell. 
How make Activity sliding in android?

```
1) MainFragment 
2) DetailActivity
```

[image]

Comment: is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Are you asking about a `ViewPager?` if that is the case. You would have to create a `FragmentActivity` (DetailActivity) and each slide would be a `Fragment`

Answer (score 2):

When you are implementing onClick use this:

```
startActivity(intent);
this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,
                R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

**slide_in_right**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shareInterpolator="false" >

<translate
android:duration="300"
android:fromXDelta="100%"
android:fromYDelta="0%"
android:toXDelta="0%"
android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

**slide_out_left**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shareInterpolator="false" >

<translate
android:duration="300"
android:fromXDelta="0%"
android:fromYDelta="0%"
android:toXDelta="-100%"
android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

Comment: and how i get data from listview? It simple open new instent with animation\

Comment: @user1088259 what data could you explain it?

Comment: i take data from server. Its contain - Title and text. I have 20 items . I want sliding between this

Comment: you have two option either send data from the intent by using putExtra  with intent or take the clicked item id and get from the data base if you are storing the data ...